# 404 error when parsing URL using jsoup

Tags: java, url, jsoup

I am getting a 404 error when using Jsoup. The call is `Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 30000)` and the URL string is `http://www.myland.co.il/%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%91-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%94`
and the URL displays fine in Chrome. The error I am getting is `java.io.IOException: 404 error loading URL http://www.myland.co.il/vmchk/×××©×-××©×§××`

Any ideas?

Comment: I managed to solve this problem using HTMLUnit. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786295/404-not-found-when-using-htmlunit

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `parse()`-method for websites, use `connect()` instead. So you can set more connection settings.

```
final String url = "http://www.myland.co.il/%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%91-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%94";

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

However the problem is the url-encoding:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404, URL=http://www.myland.co.il/vmchk/×××©×-××©×§××
```

Even decoding the url back to *utf-8* doesn't solve this.

Do you have an "alternative" url?

Comment: I use Jsoup.parse so that I can specify the connection timeout. 
When using the browser, the page is redirected from  http://www.myland.co.il/%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%91-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%94 
to http://www.myland.co.il/vmchk/%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%91-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%94
For some reason, jsoup redirects to http://www.myland.co.il/vmchk/×××©×-××©×§××
The redirect happens only during the first visit to the site. In following visits, the redirect does not happen. First visit can easily be simulated by cleaning the cookies. How can Jsoup handle the redirect?

Comment: You can set timeout with `connect()` too: `Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(<timeout millis>)`. You the `connect()` allows you to set whether Jsoup should follow redirects (or not): [followRedirects()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#followRedirects%28boolean%29) - default is `true`. Best you take a look at [connection](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html)-class too.

Comment: I use doc = Jsoup.connect(urlString).timeout(30000).followRedirects(true).get(); but still get the same error:

Comment: I looked at the connection class but this does not help much. I now use doc = Jsoup.connect(urlString).timeout(30000).followRedirects(true).get(); but still get the same error: java.io.IOException: 404 error loading URL http://www.myland.co.il/vmchk/×××©×-××©×§××

Comment: In general i think this is *not* a jsoup problem. Connection via `HttpURLConnection` doesn't work neither (same exception). Maybe because thai (?) font / charset is not supported it gets decoded with wrong characters. Hmm ... possible it works if you change charset and see how you can fix the encoding issue first.

Comment: I tried view-source and saw that the charset is utf-8 as can be seen by the line <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />. The only way I found to specify the charset in jSoup is:
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(is, "utf-8", testURL);
and the call to  url.openStream() fails with java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.myland.co.il/vmchk/×××©×-××©×§××

Comment: If there's no charset specified Jsoup will use UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

try `decodeURL()`

```
String url = "http://www.myland.co.il/%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%91-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%94";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url.decodeURL()).get();
```